# What happens when iron(III) chloride is dissolved in ethanol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, stability

I dissolved $\pu{25 mmol}$ $\ce{FeCl3*6H2O}$ in $\pu{25 ml}$ ethanol and got a **clear** ethanol solution of $\ce{FeCl3}$ 4 days ago. And I keep it in a drawer from light these four days.

However, when I opened my drawer today, the solution is not clear anymore.
And it does not recover to clear after ultrasonic treatment.
It seems that there are some yellow suspended drops/particles in the solution. I wonder what they are and what happened to my solution of ferric chloride.

[image: my unclear solution]

Comment: The insoluble stuff in suspension is probably a precipitate of $\ce{Fe(OH)3}$ produced by the hydrolysis of $\ce{FeCl3}$ according to $$\ce{FeCl3 + 3 H2O -> Fe(OH)3 + 3 HCl}$$ For some unclear reason, this reaction is more important in ethanol than in water.

Comment: Well, it's important in water, too. The solution should have been acidified to prevent that.

Comment: You also dissolved FeCl3 in a mix of ethanol and water [the water of hydration plus any water in the ethanol]. What ions are being formed, however slowly, and what is not soluble involving those ions? It probably is not a clean reaction.

Comment: See https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/zna-1983-0614/pdf on disproportionation.